# How to make a GET Request in XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, api, xmlhttprequest

I'd like to make this GET request to GitHub API: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-all-public-repositories

I have no idea how to do this however. I've done some `curl`ing, but this is the first time I'll be using HTTP and API requests.

I've tried some online tutorials, but they don't exactly show how to make a specific GET request.

Here's what I have so far:

```
function reqListener () {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
  var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
  oReq.open("GET", "https://api.github.com/");
  oReq.send();
```

Instead of a JSON with Repository information from GitHub, I'm getting the following:

```
{"current_user_url":"https://api.github.com/user","current_user_authorizations_html_url":"https://github.com/settings/connections/applications{/client_id}","authorizations_url":"https://api.github.com/authorizations","code_search_url":"https://api.github.com/search/code?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}","commit_search_url":"https://api.github.com/search/commits?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}","emails_url":"https://api.github.com/user/emails","emojis_url":"https://api.github.com/emojis","events_url":"https://api.github.com/events","feeds_url":"https://api.github.com/feeds","followers_url":"https://api.github.com/user/followers","following_url":"https://api.github.com/user/following{/target}","gists_url":"https://api.github.com/gists{/gist_id}","hub_url":"https://api.github.com/hub","issue_search_url":"https://api.github.com/search/issues?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}","issues_url":"https://api.github.com/issues","keys_url":"https://api.github.com/user/keys","notifications_url":"https://api.github.com/notifications","organization_repositories_url":"https://api.github.com/orgs/{org}/repos{?type,page,per_page,sort}","organization_url":"https://api.github.com/orgs/{org}","public_gists_url":"https://api.github.com/gists/public","rate_limit_url":"https://api.github.com/rate_limit","repository_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}","repository_search_url":"https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}","current_user_repositories_url":"https://api.github.com/user/repos{?type,page,per_page,sort}","starred_url":"https://api.github.com/user/starred{/owner}{/repo}","starred_gists_url":"https://api.github.com/gists/starred","team_url":"https://api.github.com/teams","user_url":"https://api.github.com/users/{user}","user_organizations_url":"https://api.github.com/user/orgs","user_repositories_url":"https://api.github.com/users/{user}/repos{?type,page,per_page,sort}","user_search_url":"https://api.github.com/search/users?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}"}
```

Edit: I've been able to get the first page, but I'd like to keep iterating through the pages. I don't understand the docs on how to do this. So far my code is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4)
        {
            if(xhr.status == 200)
            {
                console.log("Something went right!");
                var json_results = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                json_length = Object.keys(json_results).length
                var str = "";
                for(var i = 0; i < json_length; i++)
                {
                    str += JSON.stringify(json_results[i].description) + "\n";
                }
                document.getElementById('api-content').textContent = str;
            }
            else if(xhr.status == 404)
            {
                console.log("404 NOT FOUND!");
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("Something went wrong!");
            }
        }
    };

    xhr.open("get", "https://api.github.com/repositories", true);
    xhr.send();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function reqListener (response) {
    console.log(response);
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
oReq.open("GET", "https://api.github.com/repositories");
oReq.send();
```

Please refer to the documentation for proper usage of Github API.

Comment: And this is a single page. How would I refer to all pages? The repository page says to use something like `rel="next"`, but I'm unsure as to what that means,

Comment: The API response will include that information in your response header, as `Link -> <https://api.github.com/repositories?page=1&per_page=100&since=369>; rel="next", <https://api.github.com/repositories{?since}>; rel="first"`. See this documentation, https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination and https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/traversing-with-pagination/

Comment: @akinkide I don't know what to do with the answer you provided me. Could you explain further how to traverse through the repositories results so I can get ALL of the repositories in GitHub rather than a page at a time (or go through all of the pages)?

Comment: @FurkanToprak including`?page=2&per_page=100` will allow traversing through results from Github, hence, `https://api.github.com/repositories?page=2&per_page=100`. Read More: https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination

Answer (score 2):

XMLHttpRequest get works fine here, it is the URL which you are making the request.
Check github api docs to get the link and params required for what you need.

https://developer.github.com/v3/

Answer (score 0):

Making a GET request to `https://api.github.com/` does NOT give you result of: `a JSON with Repository information from GitHub`. You'll get a page showing a JSON of URLs to the relevant pages / information.

**solution:**

> Instead of a JSON with Repository information from GitHub, I'm getting the following:

```
{"current_user_url":"https://api.github.com/user","current_user_authorizations_html_url":"https://github.com/settings/connections/applications{/client_id}","authorizations_url":"https://api.github.com/authorizations","code_search_url":"https://api.github.com/search/code?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}","commit_search_url":"https://api.github.com/search/commits?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}","emails_url":"https://api.github.com/user/emails","emojis_url":"https://api.github.com/emojis","events_url":"https://api.github.com/events","feeds_url":"https://api.github.com/feeds","followers_url":"https://api.github.com/user/followers","following_url":"https://api.github.com/user/following{/target}","gists_url":"https://api.github.com/gists{/gist_id}","hub_url":"https://api.github.com/hub","issue_search_url":"https://api.github.com/search/issues?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}","issues_url":"https://api.github.com/issues","keys_url":"https://api.github.com/user/keys","notifications_url":"https://api.github.com/notifications","organization_repositories_url":"https://api.github.com/orgs/{org}/repos{?type,page,per_page,sort}","organization_url":"https://api.github.com/orgs/{org}","public_gists_url":"https://api.github.com/gists/public","rate_limit_url":"https://api.github.com/rate_limit","repository_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}","repository_search_url":"https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}","current_user_repositories_url":"https://api.github.com/user/repos{?type,page,per_page,sort}","starred_url":"https://api.github.com/user/starred{/owner}{/repo}","starred_gists_url":"https://api.github.com/gists/starred","team_url":"https://api.github.com/teams","user_url":"https://api.github.com/users/{user}","user_organizations_url":"https://api.github.com/user/orgs","user_repositories_url":"https://api.github.com/users/{user}/repos{?type,page,per_page,sort}","user_search_url":"https://api.github.com/search/users?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}"}
```

Decide which *"Repository information"* you want and get it from the above (JSON) listed URLs.

***For example:** (if Github user is: [VCone](https://github.com/VCone)*)

- `"user_url": "https://api.github.com/users/{user}"`
   means go to URL: `https://api.github.com/users/VCone`.
- `"user_repositories_url": "https://api.github.com/users/{user}/repos{?type,page,per_page,sort}"`
   means go to URL: `https://api.github.com/users/VCone/repos`. 
  or can be `https://api.github.com/users/VCone/repos?type=xxxx,sort=xxxx,page=xxxx`
  etc.